# What operating system concepts should I be fluent with to understand LVM in UNIX operating systems?

Tags: operating-systems, linux

I'm wondering about this. LVMs are so interesting and useful, but they are very complicated for my brain. I'm pretty sure this is due to lack of my preriquisites of computer science concepts.
So, I want to learn what concepts should I learn first in order to grasp LVMs concepts effectively. Only computer science concepts. I can't afford to learn OS from start to finish, so do tell me the core concepts in order. I'll read them myself.

Comment: At its simplest implementation, I think of LVM as merging all available disk space, across many storage devices (the physical volumes). I can then slice up this large pool of storage (the volume group) into one or (logical) volumes to store what I want, in volumes of the size I need. I have created my LVMs using Webmin: https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Logical_Volume_Management , to avoid the details of command line.